# how to make headers bold in export as csv using alasql

Tags: angularjs

how to make headers bold in export as csv using alasql

```
var data = [
  ["FirstName", "LastName"],
  ["Alan", "Tsai"],
  ["John", "Doe"]
];

var jsonData = [{
  "FirstName": "Alan",
  "LastName": "Tsai"
}, {
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Doe"
}]

window.exportData = function exportData() {
  alasql("SELECT * INTO CSV('names.csv') FROM ?", [data]);
}

   window.exporJsontData = function exporJsontData() {
  alasql("SELECT * INTO CSV('names.csv',{headers:true}) FROM ?",   [jsonData]);
}
```

In above example FirstName and Last Name should be bold.

JS fiddle for the same http://jsfiddle.net/alantsai/h2wbbkm6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is csv ?**

First thing to understand is that csv is a text file where columns values are stored separated with comma.

**Styling CSV**

So, I thing there is no styling will be saved.

**The simple reason is that**
I have never could save styled excel file in CSV format with style preserved.

**Hope your problem solved**

Comment: Thanks Mate.Yes i understand the things and that solved my problem as well. :)